# Не срабатывает transition после animation

Tags: css

```css
@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    left: -200px;
  }
  50% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

div {
  widtH: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  animation: 5s anim;
  transition: all 1s;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
}

div:hover {
  left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Оно вроде как работает но первый раз идет рывок а дальше плавно. Как исправить ситуацию?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо `left:20px;` решил использовать `margin-left: 20px;`.

```css
@keyframes anim {
  0% {
    left: -200px;
  }
  100% {
    left: 0;
  }
}

div {
  widtH: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: green;
  animation: 2.5s anim;
  transition: all 1s;
  position: absolute;
}

div:hover {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```